# Speed up JSON objects

Tags: android, json, org.json

I'm using the org.json.* library for turning my web services' result (obviously json) into json objects.  My problem is that the JSONObject and JSONArray constructors take a long time to build out the objects.  I'm not passing a very large amount of data (anywhere between 1 and 100 array items with 3-5 keys each), but even with just 4 or 5 it takes a few seconds for the constructor to finish.

Is there a way to speed this up?  Is there a faster library I could be using?

There's not a whole lot of code to show.

```
JSONArray arrayjson = new JSONArray(json);
```

Where json is a String.

Comment: Your problem is almost certainly not related to the JSON library, but to I/O or other strange coincidences. Can you produce an [SSCC Example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: please provide some code : latency could come from unapropriate declaration of variables and too many calls to the garbage collector ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might give [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) a try.  This [article](http://www.martinadamek.com/2011/02/01/adding-gson-to-android-json-parser-comparison/) seems to indicate that it has pretty good performance on Android vs the other alternatives.  [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) might be another good alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I will give gson a good look and report back any improvements.

Comment: The article referenced includes a reference to an improved version of the test, where Jackson showed to be significantly faster than Gson on Android.

Answer (score 3):

According to the performance results at https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki, for serialization with databind with strings, e.g., gson.toJson(myObject), Gson is over 10X slower than Jackson.  FastJSON beat Jackson at this same test by 2-3%.

Deserialization performance is similar, with Gson over 9x slower than Jackson, and FastJSON about 0.5% faster than Jackson.

Note: The current test results used Gson 1.6.  With Gson 1.7.1, the databind performance improved 10-15% over Gson 1.6 (but the manual and manual/tree solutions showed no improvement).  The results will hopefully be updated accordingly soon.